# LISP:How to read numbers from user and store as a list

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

I am new to lisp. I am trying to read numbers from user and want to store it as a list. For example: if the user enters `1 2 3 4 5`, then the list would contain 5 elements `(1 2 3 4 5)`. I tried `(parse-integer(read-line) :junk-allowed t)` but it returns only the first element. How should I do this? Thanks.

Comment: How about calling the parser in a loop, advancing the start each time?

Comment: The second value returned by parse-integer is a position which can be the `:start` position of the next call to parse-integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Use `read`

The simplest option is to ask the user to enter the list (with the parens) and just call [`(read)`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_rd.htm).

The second option is to put the parens yourself:

```
(read-from-string (concatenate 'string "(" (read-line) ")"))
```

### safety and security

Note that the power of the [Lisp reader](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_b.htm) can put you in trouble. E.g., if the user types [`#.(start-ww3)`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dhf.htm) instead of `(1 2 3)` at your prompt, you might not reach your bomb shelter in time.

This means that you *must* bind [`*read-eval*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_rd_eva.htm) to `nil` when calling `read` on text you do not control.

## Call `parse-integer` repeatedly

Finally, you can call [`parse-integer`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_parse_.htm) in a loop

```
(defun parse-integers (s &optional (start 0))
  (loop with num do 
    (setf (values num start) (parse-integer s :start start :junk-allowed t))
    while num collect num))
```

or recursively:

```
(defun parse-integers (s &optional (start 0))
  (multiple-value-bind (num end) 
      (parse-integer s :start start :junk-allowed t)
    (and num (cons num (parse-integers s end)))))
```

Comment: When proposing to call `read` on user input (not recommended), at least always advise to bind `*read-eval*` to `nil`.